# Submitting In-App Purchases AFTER binary has been uploaded

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, submission

I'm making a game that has a few levels that are available as in-app purchases (non-consumables).

I'm getting closer to submission time, and I really have a deadline I need to hit, so I'm running into this issue:

Can I submit In-App purchases to iTunes Connect AFTER I have submitted the app for review? I know I can add them to iTunes Connect before, but not all of the levels are ready yet, so if they tried to download them from my server they wouldn't actually get the level and would likely get rejected.

Is there any way I can add them to iTunes Connect after submission, when each one is done so the content will be live on the server?

Essentially, the app will be done a week or two before the levels will be complete, and I don't want to wait until the levels are done to submit to the app store.

The big issue I see here is I don't want to have the game released without all the In-App purchases available.

I was thinking about making a generic "token" that a user can download and redeem it for a level, but I'd rather stay away from that in case I want to have different prices for them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What about submitting what you have now, and then, after you finish the levels, submitting those in an update?

Comment: I'm thinking about that, but the levels are on schedule to be ready before the app is released (assuming regular submission times with Apple, etc) so I'd really like them to be in launch, as it adds a lot to the game. I just don't want to have a lack-luster launch with not many levels available and have it like that for a few weeks while I wait for a new update to be approved.

Comment: I don't know any other options, then, besides just submitting it and hoping that they don't get to it before you're finished. As an iOS Developer myself, it does take over a week waiting for review, so you could potentially get away with that... You could also see [here](http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/) for more up-to-date information about review times, as well as Apple's own website about App Store submissions where they post statistics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this, I figured out the answer. As long as one in app purchase is submitted with the first bundle, you can add other ones along the way, even when it's waiting for review.